# Capistrano VPS deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy to a VPS. In my `deploy.rb`:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
server "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
set :application, "riffbox"
set :user, "root"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/iv.git"
set :branch, "master"
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases
```

And I got following errors when running `cap deploy:cold`:

```
  * 2013-04-13 22:59:38 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/root/apps/riffbox/releases/20130413105936 && bundle install --gemfile /home/root/apps/riffbox/releases/20130413105936/Gemfile --path /home/root/apps/riffbox/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["198.199.74.146"]
    [198.199.74.146] executing command
 ** [out :: 198.199.74.146] **ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.**
 ** [out :: 198.199.74.146] 
    command finished in 915ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/root/apps/riffbox/releases/20130413105936; true"
    servers: ["198.199.74.146"]
    [198.199.74.146] executing command
    command finished in 907ms
**failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/root/apps/riffbox/releases/20130413105936 && bundle install --gemfile /home/root/apps/riffbox/releases/20130413105936/Gemfile --path /home/root/apps/riffbox/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 198.199.74.146**
```

I can see there are two errors, `Bundler` cannot be found and the other one failed to run the `sh` command. I followed instruction (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) to install rvm, rubygem and rails on my VPS using the `root` user.

What else I am missing?

**Update**

I am using rvm-capistrano, and installed everything using the created user, and got a different error now when deploy:cold:

> executing "if [ -d /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd
>   /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git
>   fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard
>   2afbd8fb661f62a01e0940be38e70915fc3e32ea && git clean -q -d -x -f;
>   else git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:xxx/iv.git
>   /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy && cd
>   /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy
>   2afbd8fb661f62a01e0940be38e70915fc3e32ea; fi"
>       servers: ["198.199.74.146"]
>  Password: 
>       [198.199.74.146] executing command
>   ** [198.199.74.146 :: err] **fatal: could not read Password for
>   'https://xxx@bitbucket.org':** No such device or address
>   Password: 
>       command finished in 7399ms
>   *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
>    * executing "rm -rf /home/app/riffbox/releases/20130414224249; true"
>
>       servers: ["198.199.74.146"]
>
>       [198.199.74.146] executing command
>
>       command finished in 586ms
>
>   **failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3@myapp' -c 'if [ -d /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git
>   fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard
>   2afbd8fb661f62a01e0940be38e70915fc3e32ea && git clean -q -d -x -f;
>   else git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:xxx/iv.git
>   /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy && cd
>   /home/app/riffbox/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy
>   2afbd8fb661f62a01e0940be38e70915fc3e32ea; fi'" on 198.199.74.146**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [rvm-capistrano](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano#readme) gem, it will give you access to RVM environment during deploy.

---

### A very important note:

You are using `root` user for deployment, it's overall bad practice to use directly `root` user, you should consider using a new user per application.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I created a new user in admin group, but couldn't get it to work because of the "ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed".. My question is that on the VPS which user (root or the created user) should I use to install rvm, ruby nginx etc...

Comment: yes the created user for everything, using `root` is asking for trouble.